# How to better use media queries with mixins in LESS?

Tags: css, sass, less

In SASS I used to work with media queries the following way:

Mixin:

```
.media(@width) {
  @media only screen and (min-width: @width) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

In SCSS:

```
@include media(768px) {
  .class {
    // some style
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do something similar with LESS?